# Python: Cannot Use Keyword Arguments when Inheriting from ttk.Frame

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter, keyword-argument

I am trying to create a subclass of the ttk.Frame object, but I noticed that I am unable to pass keyword arguments into its parent's init method. Here is a stripped down version of my class:

```py
from tkinter import ttk

class MyFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):                    
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, kwargs)
```

Here's an example of attempting to create an instance of my class (root is assigned to `tkinter.Tk()`):

```py
my_frame = MyFrame(root, borderwidth=5)
```

And here's the error when I try to create an instance of my class:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\csmith\Documents\tmp\frame_test.py", line 5, in __init__
ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I know it's possible to create Frame objects while using keyword arguments, but I can't seem to figure out why I can't create a class that passes it's keyword arguments to Frame's init method. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Could you show all of your code?

Comment: @Jake It's enough code to debug. When running the code that was given, you can recreate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing in `kwargs` to a function, use `**kwargs` instead. This means 'unpack as `kwargs`', since you have to put all `kwargs` in one by one. 'Unpack' means that Python will do that for you.

Change

```
super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, kwargs)
```

to

```
super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you; this seemed to solve my problem. I guess I'm a little confused about the difference between `kwargs` vs `**kwargs`. I looked at the declaration of the Frame class and noticed that it passes its keyword arguments to the Widget class without unpacking them in its init method like this: `Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)`. Is there a reason why not unpacking the keywords works in this case?

Comment: I figured out why you need to unpack the kwargs dictionary in when calling the init method for Frame and not Canvas. It's because the signature for the Cavnas init method includes a configuration dictionary: `def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):` which uses the kwargs dictionary as a valid argument without needing to unpack it. The ttk.Frame class does not include this parameter, meaning that it had to be unpacked. See this post for a more detailed explaination: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866697/cnf-argument-for-tkinter-widgets